# What is causing this Copy command to enter sleep state?

Tags: solaris, cp

I am trying to recursively copy a huge directory of installables over 25G and want to preserve the owner and group id, permission modes and so on.

So I ran the below commands:

```
bash-3.2$ date; cp -rpP /source/path/Oracle /target/path/Oracle;date;
Tue Jun  4 09:44:54 EDT 2013

...
```

---

**Some observations:**

- Today (Wed Jun  5 12:09:25 EDT 2013) I notice that it still hasn't completed and appears to be stuck somewhere. I started analyzing the process and it seems to be sleeping:

  ```
  bash-3.2$ truss -p 09431;
  read(10, 0xFFBEF288, 32768)     (sleeping...)
  ```
- The last entry also shows that its asleep.

  ```
  bash-3.2$ pflags 09431
  9431:   cp -rpP /source/path/Oracle /target/path/Oracle
          data model = _ILP32  flags = RLC|ASYNC|MSACCT|MSFORK
          flttrace = 0xfffffbff
          sigtrace = 0xfffffeff 0xffffffff
          HUP|INT|QUIT|ILL|TRAP|ABRT|EMT|FPE|BUS|SEGV|SYS|PIPE|ALRM|TERM|USR1|USR2|CLD|PWR|WINCH|URG|POLL|STOP|TSTP|CONT|TTIN|TTOU|VTALRM|PROF|XCPU|XFSZ|WAITING|LWP|FREEZE|THAW|CANCEL|LOST|XRES|JVM1|JVM2|RTMIN|RTMIN+1|RTMIN+2|RTMIN+3|RTMAX-3|RTMAX-2|RTMAX-1|RTMAX
      entryset = 0x00000401 0x04000000 0x00000000 0x00000028
                 0x80000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
      exitset  = 0xfffffffe 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffd7
                 0x7fffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff
   /1:    flags = ASLEEP  read(0xa,0xffbef288,0x8000)
  ```
- Finally tried `pfiles`

  ```
  bash-3.2$ pfiles -F 09431
  9431:   cp -rpP /source/path/Oracle /target/path/Oracle
  Current rlimit: 256 file descriptors
  0: S_IFCHR mode:0620 dev:363,0 ino:12582922 uid:502012187 gid:7 rdev:24,3
    O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_LARGEFILE
    /devices/pseudo/pts@0:3
  1: S_IFCHR mode:0620 dev:363,0 ino:12582922 uid:502012187 gid:7 rdev:24,3
    O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_LARGEFILE
    /devices/pseudo/pts@0:3
  2: S_IFCHR mode:0620 dev:363,0 ino:12582922 uid:502012187 gid:7 rdev:24,3
    O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_LARGEFILE
    /devices/pseudo/pts@0:3
  3: S_IFDIR mode:0750 dev:377,1 ino:1135681 uid:502012187 gid:502012187 size:4096
    O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY|O_LARGEFILE FD_CLOEXEC
    /source/path/Oracle
  4: S_IFDIR mode:0750 dev:377,1 ino:1135682 uid:502012187 gid:502012187 size:4096
    O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY|O_LARGEFILE FD_CLOEXEC
    /source/path/Oracle/Middleware
  5: S_IFDIR mode:0750 dev:377,1 ino:14640507 uid:502012187 gid:502012187 size:4096
    O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY|O_LARGEFILE FD_CLOEXEC
    /source/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects
  6: S_IFDIR mode:0750 dev:377,1 ino:14640508 uid:502012187 gid:502012187 size:4096
    O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY|O_LARGEFILE FD_CLOEXEC
    /source/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem2
  7: S_IFDIR mode:0750 dev:377,1 ino:6480147 uid:502012187 gid:502012187 size:4096
    O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY|O_LARGEFILE FD_CLOEXEC
    /source/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem2/EssbaseServer
  8: S_IFDIR mode:0750 dev:377,1 ino:6480149 uid:502012187 gid:502012187 size:4096
    O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY|O_LARGEFILE FD_CLOEXEC
    /source/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem2/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1
  9: S_IFDIR mode:0750 dev:377,1 ino:6480151 uid:502012187 gid:502012187 size:4096
    O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY|O_LARGEFILE FD_CLOEXEC
    /source/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem2/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1/bin
  10: S_IFIFO mode:0660 dev:377,1 ino:9088704 uid:502012187 gid:502012187 size:0
    O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE
    /source/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem2/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1/bin/ESSBASE1_1
  11: S_IFREG mode:0660 dev:326,22000 ino:128325 uid:502012187 gid:502012187 size:0
    O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE
    /target/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem2/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1/bin/ESSBASE1_1
  ```

---

**UPDATE:** *Note that the above `cp` process has been killed. So below observations are trying to reproduce the issue.*

- **File** that is getting blocked:

  ```
  bash-3.2$ ls -l ESSBASE1_1
  prw-rw----   1 kent   kent         0 Nov 22  2011 ESSBASE1_1
  ```
- When I try to cp this file individually:

  ```
  bash-3.2$ cp ESSBASE1_1 ESSBASE1_1kent  # PID = 08745

  ...
  ```

  it hangs too.
- Looking at `pflags`, it seems to be sleeping.

  ```
  bash-3.2$ pflags 08745
  8745:   cp ESSBASE1_1 ESSBASE1_1kent
          data model = _ILP32  flags = MSACCT|MSFORK
  /1:    flags = ASLEEP  read(0x3,0xffbf6bc8,0x8000)
  ```
- Searching for all other processes using this file

  ```
  bash-3.2$ fuser -f /source/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem2/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1/bin/ESSBASE1_1
  /source/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem2/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1/bin/ESSBASE1_1:     8745o   25057o
  ```

  Note that the 'o' indicates that the process is using the file as an open file.
- Finding at the processes:

  ```
  bash-3.2$ pstree | grep 8745
   | | |       |--- 09695 kent grep 8745
   | |         \--- 08745 kent cp ESSBASE1_1 ESSBASE1_1kent
  bash-3.2$ pstree | grep 25057
   | | |       \--- 09700 kent grep 25057
   | |   |-+- 25057 kent 86:43 /some/path/Oracle/Middlewa
  ```

  Process with PID 25057 is a server process.
- The open file is on a mount-point. It's a NAS disk.

  ```
  bash-3.2$ cat /etc/mnttab | grep apps
  server1.com:/vol/server1_nec_nosnap0/dev_apps   /source/path/       nfs     rw,xattr,dev=5e40001    1362894854
  ```

---

- Can anyone help me understand what is causing the copy command to freeze up?
- I can guess that the application is running and that might be in some way preventing any other process from accessing a particular file.
- But in such a scenario I would expect `cp` to abort and throw me an error rather than stay blocked indefinitely.
- As per the update, it seems process `PID=25057` seems to be using the file as an open file. But why does this block the `cp` command?

Comment: Few quesetions but the read it's hanging on is for `/source/path/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem2/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1/bin/ESSBASE1_1` Is that a file or directory? Is it on NFS per chance? Do you know if xfn or other types of automount is configured on this server? What happens if you just try to copy that file directly?

Comment: Hi @JoelDavis, I updated the post to answer your questions. The file is on NFS. I know that the mounts are automounted whenever I cd to the directory after a reboot, but I do not know how to check if its configured on Solaris 10.

Comment: it actually looks like Flup hit the nail on the head, it is definitely a FIFO and if you're trying to copy a FIFO you will be waiting there a while, especially if the other side is waiting on data from CP.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it @JoelDavis. I read up on [FIFOs](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/fifos.html) and it seems that `rsync` is the best way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at your `pfiles` output for file descriptor 10, you'll notice that the file is a FIFO; this is also evidenced by the `p` type in your `ls` listing.  The nature of a FIFO is that reads will block unless another process is writing data, and this is why your `cp` got stuck when trying to read its contents.

To get around the problem, you could use `rsync` to copy the directory tree instead.

```
rsync -a /source/path/Oracle /target/path
```

`rsync` is clever enough to make a duplicate FIFO rather than read from the original one.  Note that you don't specify `Oracle` for the destination, as `rsync` will create the directory there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Flup! Looking into `rsync`